# How can you count the occurrence of 1 from 1 to 99,999,999 (1 short of 100 million) and total up how many 1s were there

Tags: c#

i started learn c# and in such task. i have already do it this is the code:

```
string y = "";
int count = 0;
string x  = "";
string[] arr = new string[100000000];

for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
{ 
    x = i.ToString() + x;
}

Console.WriteLine(x);

for (int j = 0; j < x.Length; j++)
{
    y = x.Substring(j, 1);

    switch (y)
    {
        case "1":
             count ++;
             break;

        default:
            break;
    } 
}

Console.WriteLine(count);
```

The code worked correctly in case of small range (0 to 1000) but when running it for a range of 100 million it does not produce any result (i waited for while but no output)plus it looks like my code is not efficient way. my question now is what is the problem in this code and if there was a better solution for this task.

Comment: How long did you wait? 100 million iterations is a *lot*, even for fast operations

Comment: Creating a HUMUNGOUS string like x is never a good idea - the CLR has to try and find a space in memory for all of it.  It's better (and negligible cost) to work with one number at a time - ie. nest your j loop inside your i loop.

Comment: Might want to look into `StringBuilder`. Strings are immutable by the way, every += creates a new instance.

Comment: I got it to work using a StringBuilder and 10,000,000. 100 million produced a StackOverflowException on my 12GB machine.

Comment: Hint: Strings are the wrong way to go about this.  Find an *efficient* way to *calculate* the "1"s between 1-and-100, then 1-and-1000, then 1-and-10,000.  Break the problem down, then build the solution up.

Comment: is this a [FizzBuzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz) challenge?

Comment: If you mean 1, 11, 21, 31 as "ones", then the answer can be calculated trivially. Try to find a solution that doesn't store each individual possibility and then enumerates through them searching for a match. You are going to take a very long time to run, and eventually run out of memory with your solution.

Comment: Do you need to do it in code? Because otherwise, as @StarPilot said, the answer can be found fairly trivially: there is a single 1 in the range of 0-9, when we move to tens where there are now 10 numbers containing ones (91, 81, 71, 61, 51, 41, 31, 21, 11,1). Same story for the hundreds  and thousands and so on... In each case you only  need to worry about the extra digit you added on, not the entire number since you know that for each tens digit, there will be just one '1' in the single digits.

Comment: @chase Florell
no it is not :)....just an assignment for beginners

Comment: @Mewa
no it in not a symmetric count of 1s between the tens ranges..you forgot about the (10,11,12,13,14,15......19): 1s count=11
(20,21,22,....29):1s count=1
 and so (110,11,112...,119) :1s count=21

Comment: @MaiAmin, fair enough, I wasn't paying enough attention. But you can say that between 0-9 there is one '1', then between 10-99, there are 18 (10+8*1), then between 100-999 there are (100+8*(1+18)).  Then with thousands you'd have (1000+8*(100+8*(1+18))).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your biggest problem is string concatenation. A big mistake C# newbies make is thinking that strings are mutable, because they behave that way to an external observer. In fact, they are treated as immutable in memory; every time `x = i.ToString() + x` executes in your loop, two new strings are created, one of them replacing the previous reference kept by X. `i.ToString()` and the old `x` value leave scope, but aren't removed from memory until the GC can get to them. So, this algorithm is making the memory-management layer of the runtime work uncommonly hard.

In addition, you have a 100-million-element array, arr, taking up space in the sandbox. This probably isn't really slowing you down, but it's certainly wasting memory given it's not used.

The "switch" statement is too much for what you want to do. The exact same operation can be specified more simply (and with fewer underlying operations) thusly: `if(y=="1") count++;`.

Lastly, if you want a single character from a string in most C-style languages, you can simply treat the string as an array of characters (which it is): `y = x[j];` will give you the same result as `y=x.Substring(j,1)`, it will just be a character variable instead of a one-character string, and it should be much faster because you're not spinning through the logic in the String.Substring() method.

---

Instead, you get the same result by just taking each string in order and counting the 1s in it, and adding that to a grand total. Your existing implementation will work if tweaked that way, but a little Linq will make the code cleaner (though not necessarily faster):

```
for(var i=1; i < 100000000; i++)
    count += i.ToString().Count(c=>c=='1');
```

You could even one-line it with a pure Linq solution:

```
var count = Enumerable.Range(1,99999999).Aggregate(0, (s, i) => s + i.ToString().Count(c=>c == '1'));
```

Breaking this down:

- `Enumerable.Range` produces an "enumerable" (one-way iterable series) of incrementing integers starting with the first parameter and continuing until the second parameter's number of numbers have been produced.
- `Aggregate` basically wraps a compounding loop; it takes a "seed" value (0), passes that in as the first parameter of the anonymous method along with the first element of the source collection, then takes the result of that method and feeds it back into the lambda statement along with the next element, and so on until it's done this for every element.
- The lambda statement `(s, i) => s + i.ToString().Count(c=>c == '1')` takes two integers ("`s`eed" and "`i`nteger"), turns the integer into a string, counts the number of '1' characters in that string, and adds that total to `s`. The returned value of the lambda is that sum.

Other things to think about:

- In the general case this may not work, but you know that no number greater than 99,999,991 in your series will have any '1' digits, so by continuing beyond that number you're just wasting time (not much in this case, but still).
- String parsing isn't bad, but integer math is typically *much* faster. For each number, try dividing by 10, then modulo'ing by 10. This will produce each digit of the number, that you can compare with 1 and increment "count" if true. It will take more lines of code, but it will likely still work out faster than ToString()ing each number, as that requires more computational steps to determine the character value for each digit and put them together (and less memory, as integer values can be operated on more or less in place, so instead of needing a string for every number, you need three integer variables for the whole loop):

  ```
  var count = 0;
  for(var i=1; i<100000000; i++)
  { 
      var j = i;
      while(j > 0)
      {
          if(j % 10) == 1) 
              count++;
          j /= 10;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to count them one by one, you can directly calculate the result.

If you count for fewer digits, you can see there is a pattern in the results:

```
1 digit  -> 1
2 digits -> 20
3 digits -> 300
4 digits -> 4000
```

So I suppose the problem can be generalized as:

```
count = digits * 10 ^ (digits - 1)
```

In this case, `digits = 8`, so `count = 8 * 10 ^ 7 = 80.000.000`

Note: Of course this method only works for the full intervals (0-999...), not for arbitrary ones (like 37-95). But your examples were all full intervals, so I assumed that's only what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by counting from 1 to your target number, and for each of those numbers, examine each digit to see if it matches the one you're searching for. This should be MUCH faster than a string comparison.

Here's an example:

```
public static int GetCountOfDigitInNumber(int sourceNumber, int digitToSearchFor)
{
    if (digitToSearchFor < -9 || digitToSearchFor > 9)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("digitToSearchFor", "Must be a single digit");

    if (digitToSearchFor < 0) digitToSearchFor *= -1;
    if (sourceNumber < 0) sourceNumber *= -1;

    var count = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= sourceNumber; i++)
    {
        var numberToExamine = i;

        while (numberToExamine > 0)
        {
            var lastDigit = numberToExamine % 10;
            if (lastDigit == digitToSearchFor) count++;
            numberToExamine /= 10;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Example usage:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var number = 99999999;

    var countOfOnes = GetCountOfDigitInNumber(number, 1);

    Console.WriteLine("There are {0} ones in the range of numbers from 1 to {1}", 
        countOfOnes, number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of 1's using the following technique

1 - 9 = 1

1 - 99 =  10 + R(1 -9) * 10  = 20

1 - 999 = 100 + Result(1-99) * 10 = 300

1 - 9999 =  1000 + Result(1 - 999)*10 = 4000

1 - 99999 =  10000 + Result(1 - 999)*10 = 50000

And when there is a 1 in any digit position, it would mean that 1 repeats for N times, where N is the digits after the position of 1. 
For example in 1235, 1 repeats for 235 atleast. So the total number of 1's would be

1235: (235+1+300)+(100+2*20)+(10+3*1)+(1) = 690

code snippet...

```
    static List<int> GetDigits(int n)
    {
        List<int> digits = new List<int>();
        while (n > 0)
        {
            digits.Add(n % 10);
            n = n / 10;
        }

        return digits;
    }

    static int GetOnesCount(int n)
    {
        int count = 0;
        Dictionary<int, int> digitPlaceValue = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        List<int> digits = GetDigits(n);
        digitPlaceValue[0] = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < digits.Count();i++)
        {
            digitPlaceValue[i] = (int)Math.Pow(10, (i - 1)) + (10 * digitPlaceValue[i - 1]);
        }

        for (int index= digits.Count()-1; index > 0; index--)
        {
            if (digits[index] > 1)
            {
                count = count + (int)Math.Pow(10, index) + digits[index] * digitPlaceValue[index];
            }
            else 
            {
                count = count + (digitPlaceValue[index] + n % (int)Math.Pow(10, index) + 1) * digits[index];
            }                
        }

        return n % 10 >= 1? count+1: count;
    }
```